# Trying to transfer files for the target user

Tags: c#

today we were trying to transfer files with using C# but there are some problems here i don't really know what is wrong

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace FileTransfer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string curDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            var userDir = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile));
            string path = curDir + @"\1.jar";
            string path2 = userDir + @"\Desktop\2.jar";
            File.Move(path, path2);
         
          
        }
    }
}
```

[It says 1.jar file cannot found.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXlum.png%60%60)

Comment: You are looking for 1.jar in the /debug/ folder

Comment: Well, the exception tells you everything, the file is simply not there. What is unclear?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 string path = Path.Combine(curDir,"1.jar");
 string path2 = Path.Combine(userDir,"Desktop","2.jar");
 //if this still doesn't work, put  a breakpoint after these two lines
```

When your breakpoint is hit look at the value of `path`. Is there a even file at that location? If not, you need build your path correctly.

Also, it would be a good idea to check if the file exists before you try to move it:

```
if(!File.Exists(path))
{
    //handle this scenario here
    return;
}
File.Move(path,path2);
```

Comment: Hi, im trying to make a c# program which has a button for transfer files to target directory,
but when I try to use setup file's current directory it's different than I think and i can't add my destination file to there for transfer my file.

I'm trying to add my destination file to Setup folder but i couldn't find the way to do that.

Comment: Then your question needs to say that. What is the value of `path`? What is the value that you expect `path` to have?

Comment: First, the user will unpack the zip file which contains setup.exe and destination file and the user will open setup.exe and the screen will pop up with button which says "transfer files".When the user click that button the command will take that destination file and transfer that to target location that's what i want to do.

Comment: Great, so what is your problem?

Comment: My problem is targeting the destination file im using SystemIO's CurrentDirectory option to do that but when i try to use it it couldn't find the directory of that setup because the setup's directory starts in somewhere in windows so i cannot find that location

Comment: "somewhere in windows" is not a location that we can help you find. What is the location of your "destination file"?